# Change location of a shape inside canvas in word 2013 using VBA

Tags: vba, canvas, ms-word, shapes

I have a shape (rectangle) created inside a canvas in Microsoft word 2013, with Left:=100
But when I read the left property of the shape, I get a number different from the one I have set in creation phase!

```
Sub DRTEXT()
  Dim shp1 As Shape, shpCanvas As Shape
Set shpCanvas = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddCanvas(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=400, Height:=400)
Set shp1 = shpCanvas.CanvasItems.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
        Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=100)


      MsgBox shp1.Left '(shows the number 5!)
      shp1.Left = 200
      MsgBox shp1.Left
End Sub
```

I feel this might be of the shape being inside a canvas which wont let me to move the shape as I want.
Any clues?
Many thanks